# Боковой скролл при изменение разрешения

Tags: html, css

В Google Chrome есть возможность "Toggle Device Toolbar", так же на мобильных и планшетных версиях появляется небольшая прокрутка по оси Х. Ставил различные стили, для блокировки, но ничего не помогло.
[Вот страница на которой это происходит](https://rabotnikof.ru/testing-main-page/)

Даже при удаление всех элементов на странице остаётся этот скролл. С чем он связан? Кто может подсказать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сайте, для элемента `<div class="info row justify-content-between">` вы указали ширину как `100vw`. Укажите 100%.

100vw не учитывает ширину прокрутки
Этот вопрос [множество](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one/23367686) раз обсуждался

Comment: до этого были сбои и задал в "vw". залил на сайт и появились другие сбои. после вашего комментария заменил и всё нормально стало. спасибо большое!